# map object.keys into string from array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array, this for example:

```
interface: [
    { _id: '1', name: 'Foo' },
    { _id: '2', name: 'bar },
    { _id: '3', name: 'boo}
]
```

i'd now like to map this to a single string ->

```
this.dataSource.data = data.data.map(item => ({
     interface: item.interfaces.name,
}));
```

so that the result inside the `dataSource.data.interface` looks like `'Foo, bar, boo'`

Comment: That's a reduce, not a map.

Comment: do you like to update `interface`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the `name` property and join the array.

```js
var data = { interface: [{ _id: '1', name: 'Foo' }, { _id: '2', name: 'bar' }, { _id: '3', name: 'boo' }]};

data.interface = data.interface.map(({ name }) => name).join(', ');

console.log(data);
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, this works great!!!! Acceptable in 8 minutes :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use Array.prototype.reduce:

```js
const concatString = data.interface.reduce((acc, value, index, arr) => {
    const str = index !== arr.length - 1 ? `${value.name}, ` : value.name;
    return acc += str;
    }, "");
```